# Packing and unpacking elements from list in R

Tags: r, list, packing

I have two questions related to using list in R and I am trying to see how I can improve my naive solution. I have seen questions on [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376506/how-to-extract-elements-from-list-of-lists) here but the approach described there is not helping.

#### Q1:

MWE:

```
a  <- c(1:5)
b  <- "adf"
c  <- array(rnorm(9), dim = c(3,3) )
```

- Make a list, say with name "packedList", while preserving the name of
  all variables.
- Current solution: `packedList <- list(a = a, b = b, c = c)`

However, if the number of variables (three in above problem i.e. `a, b, c`) is
   large (say we have 20 variables), then my current solution may not be
   the best.

This is idea is useful while returning large number of variables from
   a function.

#### Q2:

MWE: Given `packedList`, extract variables a, b, c

- I would like to extract all elements in the given list (i.e. packedList) to the environment while preserving their names. This is reverse of task 1.

For example: Given variable packedList in the environment, I can define a, b, and c as follows:

```
 a <- packedList$a
 b <- packedList$b
 c <- packedList$c
```

However, if the number of variables is very large then my solution can be cumbersome. 
- After some Google search, I found [one solution](http://www.r-bloggers.com/extract-objects-from-a-list/) but I am not sure if it is the most elegant solution either. The solution is shown below:

```
 x <- packedList
 for(i in 1:length(x)){
       tempobj <- x[[i]]
       eval(parse(text=paste(names(x)[[i]],"= tempobj")))
 }
```

Comment: you can use zeallot package in r for unpacking.
library(zeallot)
c(a,b,c) %<-%  c(1,2,3)
> a
[1] 1
> b
[1] 2
> c
[1] 3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are most likely looking for `mget` (Q1) and `list2env` (Q2).

Here's a small example:

```
ls()  ## Starting with an empty workspace
# character(0)

## Create a few objects
a  <- c(1:5)
b  <- "adf"
c  <- array(rnorm(9), dim = c(3,3))

ls()  ## Three objects in your workspace
[1] "a" "b" "c"

## Pack them all into a list
mylist <- mget(ls())
mylist
# $a
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# 
# $b
# [1] "adf"
# 
# $c
#             [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
# [1,]  0.70647167  1.8662505  1.7941111
# [2,] -1.09570748  0.9505585  1.5194187
# [3,] -0.05225881 -1.4765127 -0.6091142

## Remove the original objects, keeping just the packed list   
rm(a, b, c)

ls()  ## only one object is there now
# [1] "mylist"

## Use `list2env` to recreate the objects
list2env(mylist, .GlobalEnv)
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
ls()  ## The list and the other objects...
# [1] "a"      "b"      "c"      "mylist"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

In the scenario where we have four variables in the environment, (say a,b,c,d) but we only want to make a list for three variables ( a,b,c) then `mget(ls())` won’t  work. Any thoughts on how to go around it?

Comment: @skaur, just supply a character vector of the values you want: `mget(c("a", "b", "c"))`.