# elements from list of list in R

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list of list as follow :

```
l = list(list(v = numeric(0), pos = 10), list(v = numeric(0), pos = 10), 
    list(v = numeric(0), pos = 10), list(v = 1.227, pos = 19), 
    list(v = 1.227, pos = 19), list(v = 15.2, pos = 19))
```

I would like to extract element `v` from each list.
I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376506/how-to-extract-elements-from-list-of-lists) slution, but it does not work for me. The first method using `rapply` and `unique` function will include the `pos` values as well and also I would like to keep all `v` values even if they are repeated or they are zero or `numeric(0)` !
The second method with :

```
matrix(unlist(l),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
```

Is also not working because I have some `numeric(0)` in my lists for the value `v` !

Comment: What is the expected output, a vector?  If so you'd need to decide what the zero length entries should be recoded as (e.g. `NA`).

Comment: @H1 yes, I expect a vector contains all `v` values and either `NA` or `'-'` for the `numeric(0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
sapply(l, `[`, "v")

$v
numeric(0)

$v
numeric(0)

$v
numeric(0)

$v
[1] 1.227

$v
[1] 1.227

$v
[1] 15.2
```

Or if you mean a vector containing values from each list:

```
vec <- sapply(l, `[`, "v")
vec[lengths(vec) == 0] <- NA
unlist(vec)

     v      v      v      v      v      v 
    NA     NA     NA  1.227  1.227 15.200
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, even if I am using `lapply(l, '[[', "v")` outcome is still in a list ! how could I get just the `v` values in a vector format ?

Comment: Updated the post.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use the `purrr::map()` variants which have an argument for handling NULL or zero length entries.

```
library(purrr)

map_dbl(l, "v", .default = NA)
[1]     NA     NA     NA  1.227  1.227 15.200
```

Answer (score 1):

You could program a small `extractR`.

```
extractR <- function(l, v) {
  r <- sapply(l, `[`, "v")
  sapply(r, function(i) ifelse(length(i) == 0, NA, i))
}

extractR(l, "v")
#  v      v      v      v      v      v 
# NA     NA     NA  1.227  1.227 15.200
```